# Create custom code snippet in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

Like the title says, how do you create custom code snippets in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a link to a utility for Creating/editing Snippets. It works for more languages than just VB despite the classification in the link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb973770.aspx

Answer (score 16):

This was just released too: http://codeplex.com/SnippetDesigner

> The Snippet Designer is a plugin which enhances the Visual Studio IDE to allow a richer and more productive code snippet experience...
>
> #### Features
>
> A Snippet editor integrated inside of the IDE which supports **C#, Visual Basic, JavaScript, HTML, XML** and **SQL**
>
> - Access it by opening any .snippet file or going to File -> New -> File -> Code Snippet File
> - It uses the native Visual Studio code editor so that you can write the snippets in the same enviorment you write your code.
> - It lets you easily mark replacements by a convenient right click menu.
> - It displays properties of the snippet inside the Visual Studio properties window...
>
> A Snippet Explorer tool window to search snippets on your computer.
>
> - It is located under View -> Other Windows -> Snippet Explorer
> - This tool window contains a code preview window which lets to peek inside the snippet to see what it is without opening the file.
> - Maintains an index of snippets on your computer for quick searching.
> - Provides a quick way to find a code snippet to use, edit or delete...

Answer (score 8):

The MSDN links are nice, but sometimes I prefer simple [tutorials](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/080724.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Tools->Code Snippets Manager

To get your list of directories. Select (or Add) My Code Snippets.

The snippets themselves have to be created as separate files with a .snippet extension.

Here is a tutorial on using and creating them: [Code Snippets in Visual Studio](http://www.dotnetjunkies.ddj.com/Article/C95AC204-DE44-4D4A-A2B7-1EB1BE14A8A1.dcik)

Answer (score 0):

See official write-up here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx